# Cohomology of complex manifold vs cohomology of its complex submanifold

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, cv.complex-variables, complex-geometry, complex-manifolds

Let $X$ be a smooth complex analytic manifold. Let $Z\subset X$ be a smooth compact analytic submanifold. Let $A$ be a holomorphic vector bundle over $X$. Assume that
$$H^i(Z, A|_Z)=0 \mbox{ for any } i>0. $$

> Is it true that for any open neighborhood $U$ of $Z$ there exists an open neighborhood $V\subset U$ of $Z$ such that
>   $$H^i(V, A)=0 \mbox{ for any } i>0.$$

A reference would be helpful.

Remark. In my case $Z$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^1$ and $A$ is the trivial line bundle. Moreover the normal bundle of $Z$ is isomorphic to direct sum of several copies of $\mathcal{O}(1)$ (I am not sure if it is relevant).

Comment: Ah, ok, $Z =\Bbb{CP}^1$ is a quite different situation! I should have assumed that's what you meant - my apologies.

Comment: @MikeMiller: Sorry, there was a misprint. I fixed it.  Thank you.